# what does this sentence mean?

Tags: python

I read python [PEP100](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0100/) today. In the part of 'Unicode Default Encoding', It refer that 'The Unicode implementation has to make some assumption about the
    encoding of 8-bit strings passed to it for coercion and about the
    encoding to as default for conversion of Unicode to strings when
    no specific encoding is given.'

My question is, What does '8-bit strings' means? Does it mean ASCII?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is a 7-bit encoding. Most text encodings (including UTF-8 and ISO-8859) are 8-bit encodings.

Generally speaking, anything beyond the basic ASCII character set needs more than 7 bits to encode. So when dealing with international data, you usually deal with encodings that can use multiple bytes per encoded character. Python will automatically try to decode byte strings to Unicode when you try to combine Unicode and byte string types, and the default encoding (in python 2) is ASCII. This is a frequent source of UnicodeDecodeError exceptions in Python.

You really want to read up on Unicode and text encodings before you proceed though. I can recommend:

- Joel Spolsky's [minimum Unicode article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: If `ASCII` is just 128 characters, then why does `chr()` supports a range of `(0-255)`? I just read on wikipedia that `ASCII` is `7 bits`, but chr() confused me.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: The python string type isn't limited to 7 bits. The ISO-8859 standard re-uses ASCII, and uses the other 128 values as latin characters such as å and é. In fact, the python string type is just a sequence of bytes, that *usually* are interpreted as text. The *real* python text type (in python 2) is the unicode type.

Comment: Thanks it's much more clear now, and the term for 128-255 chars is extended ASCII. from [wikipedia:](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) `The use of the term Extended ASCII is sometimes criticized, because it can be mistakenly interpreted that the ASCII standard has been updated to include more than 128 characters or that the term unambiguously identifies a single encoding, both of which are untrue.`

Answer (score 2):

`UTF-8` is used to support a large range of characters. In UTF-8, up to 4 bytes can be used to represent a single character.

`ASCII` only defines 128 character. So only `7` bits. But is normally stored with 8 bits/character. RS232 (old serial communication) can be used with bytes of 7 bits